# MySQL Blob not showing up correctly

Tags: php, mysql, blobs

Hi I asked a similar question earlier about retrieving an image from a MySQL database Blob.

I am using code as:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); // change it to the right extension 
print $image;   //where image is the blob file
```

This code is nested inside of a webpage, so should I still modify the header? When I include the header() it removes all of the webpage code which I assume is because I am changing the file type the browser is rendering to image/jpeg? How can i show the image inside of a webpage? Thanks!

Comment: please properly format your code by highlighting it after you paste/type it in and press the code button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

You can't show an image inside a webpage (well you [can](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/), but that's a different story and probably not what you want). You need to put the code that retrieves the image from a database into a separate file, and include this file in your web page using

```
<img src="filename.php">
```